# Tensorflow Keras preprocessing layers

Tags: tensorflow, keras

At the moment i apply all preprocessing to the dataset.
But i saw that i can make the preprocessing as part of the model.
I read that the layer preprocessing is inactive at test time but what is about the rezizing layer?
For example:

```
model = Sequential([
  layers.experimental.preprocessing.Resizing(180, 180),
  layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255),
  layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  ...
```

What happens if i now use model.predict(img), will the img automatically be resized or do i have still to rezize the img before the prediction?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the preprocessing layers starting with `Random` are disabled at evaluation/test time.

In your case, the layers `Resizing` and `Rescaling` will be enabled in every case.

You can check in the source code whether or not the layer you are interested takes a `training` boolean argument in its method `call`, and use that boolean in a `control_flow_util.smart_cond`.

For example, the layer [`Resizing`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/preprocessing/image_preprocessing.py#L73-L121) does not :

> ```
> class Resizing(PreprocessingLayer):
>
>     def call(self, inputs):
>         outputs = image_ops.resize_images_v2(
>         images=inputs,
>         size=[self.target_height, self.target_width],
>         method=self._interpolation_method)
>     return outputs
> ```

While the layer [`RandomFlip`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/preprocessing/image_preprocessing.py#L356-L432) does :

> ```
> class RandomFlip(PreprocessingLayer):
>
>   def call(self, inputs, training=True):
>     if training is None:
>       training = K.learning_phase()
>
>     def random_flipped_inputs():
>       flipped_outputs = inputs
>       if self.horizontal:
>         flipped_outputs = image_ops.random_flip_left_right(flipped_outputs,
>                                                            self.seed)
>       if self.vertical:
>         flipped_outputs = image_ops.random_flip_up_down(
>             flipped_outputs, self.seed)
>       return flipped_outputs
>
>     output = control_flow_util.smart_cond(training, random_flipped_inputs,
>                                           lambda: inputs)
>     output.set_shape(inputs.shape)
>     return output
> ```